# Need help getting and intalling zlib1g-dev on Ubuntu 14.04. Error Couldn't find any package by regex

Tags: 14.04, zlib

I use

```
sudo apt-get install https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/zlib1g-dev
```

and this is what ensues:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package https
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package'
```

How can I get this to work on my version of Linux? I haven't had much luck in finding this and I'm new to linux. (Again, my version of Linux is Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: The normal way to install the package from the repository is simply `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`: no explicit URL should be involved in the command. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: This worked. Im stupid. Should I just delete this question?

Comment: No, just leave it to teach someone new to Linux deb about about how to install via apt-get.

Comment: @steeldriver: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby sorry - done

Comment: @steeldriver: done too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although `apt-get` obtains packages from online repositories, the actual URLs are resolved behind the scenes using information from the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and any additional files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Hence to install a package using `apt-get`, you should specify only the package name: in this case, that's just `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: **@fappycow:** As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: certainly, kind sir